# mod_expires doesn't set expiry for images (png,jpeg,gif)

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers, apache-2.2

I am using this below configuration in my apache2.conf

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 month"

</IfModule>
```

Its working for css and js

```
curl -I example.com/assests/css/global.css

 Expires: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 09:28:17 GMT
```

but when i curl any image file

```
curl -I example.com/assets/images/banner-16-water-purifier.jpg 

Expires: Sun, 17 Aug 2014 09:29:10 GMT
```

As you can see for jped its not working. Same applies with every image (jpeg/png/gif)

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks correct and tests OK on Apache 2.2.22. Check if you have any mod_expires directives (ExpiresByType or ExpiresDefault) elsewhere that are overriding apache.conf.

Start with any .htaccess files in the images path, including the root web folder, /assets/, and /assets/images/. Unless you've disabled the use of .htaccess in those folders, directives in .htaccess will override configuration set anywhere else.

Next check your virtual host file under /apache2/sites-available/, and then any other configuration files included by apache2.conf, such as /apache2/httpd.conf, /apache2/mods-available/expires.conf (if it exists), and any files under /apache2/conf.d/.

I ran into something similar when adding mod_expire directives to a virtual host configuration. I was wondering why it still showed a 30 day expiration when I had set it to something else, but then noticed caching software on the site had added ExpiresByType and ExpiresDefault to an .htaccess file.